# Getting amazon MWS shipments item condition from API

Tags: amazon-mws

I would like to get Shipment and shipment item information. But ListInboundShipmentItems return too few information. I need to get Shipment item's title and Condition(New ,used etc). Where can I get those info.

Comment: Please add more specific code you're encountering the issue with.

Comment: I just want to know where can I (Which module,function) get  information about shipment items condition and title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Fulfillment Inbound Shipment API](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inbound/FBAInbound_Overview.html) deals with shipments, no so much contents.  You would have to query the [Product API](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMyPriceForSKU.html) for title and condition or since these are products you are sending to Amazon, maybe pull this data from your own system if you have one in place.